# SQL insert into another table migration with group by having max()

Tags: sql, group-by, migration, mariadb, max

I got the following problem. I got two tables and want to move one column data to another table.

The tables are house and door. I want to move the column data 'street' to house. But there are multiple doors for the house (with same house_id). So I need to aggregate them and want to take the 'street' input from the newest 'created_at' record.

[situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxv6K.png)

My first attempt is:

```
insert into house h ('street') 
    select street 
    from door d 
    where d.house_id = h.id 
    group by house_id 
    having max(created_at)
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you use: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you actually want an `update` query, to set the value of `street` on existing rows in `house`.

One option is a correlated subquery with a row-limitig clause:

```
update house 
set street = (
    select d.street
    from door d
    where d.house_id = house.id
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1
)
```

The `limit` syntax varies across databases - but (almost) all have an equivalent functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are right. "Insert into" is just for new records, but I want to update the house data.